# You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "folder"

Tags: dual-boot, permissions

I had Windows installed before and I downloaded some files while using it.Then I installed Backtrack 5 R3 as dual boot and copied the files on windows to BT when BT was booted, and it was successful. (Also I always logged in as root on BT) Then I deleted Windows and installed Ubuntu 14.04 as dual boot and copied the files on BT to Ubuntu.

The problem is that when I want to open or access the files on Ubuntu when Ubuntu is booted, i can't; I get the error message

```
You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “files”
```

I can however use the `ls` command with `sudo` to `sudo ls files` but can't use `cd`; when I try I get `sudo: cd: command not found`.

The way I found that worked was to log in as root on terminal and open/access the files that way. But it wasn't efficient; I still couldn't open the files via graphical file manager. Then I looked it up on many threads and only thing i found that worked was `sudo chmod go+rx files` but the problem with this is that it makes only the `files` folder accessible, not the subfolders, and if I try using the same command to the subfolders one by one it works but I've got hundreds of subfolders which also have subfolders in them.

So I'm asking if there's a more practical way of doing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the `-R` option to recursively change all the permissions of each files and directories under a specified directory. An example, recursively add read and write permissions for the owner and group on foldername:

```
sudo chmod -R ug+rw foldername
```

Read [more about permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) ...

Comment: -1 for suggesting `chmod *`

Comment: It was a mistake of mine, edited **Zanna**. @Carles

Comment: Yes now it's not dangerous, but I don't think that would have worked. The dangerous answer did work! If you add to `chown` the structure, if would work (I wrote an answer just now)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of giving the whole directory structure insecure permissions that allow any user to write whatever they like to any file in it, make yourself the owner (recursively, using the `-R` flag):

```
sudo chown -R $USER: files
```

There's probably no need for `chmod` at all, but if you still have problems, check that the owner does have read, write and execute permissions on the directories, and read and write permissions on the files, by using `find` from the parent directory:

```
find files -type d ! -perm -u=rwx
```

If you find something, add an `-exec` to change the mode:

```
find files -type d ! -perm -u=rwx -exec chmod u+rwx {} +
```

Then for the regular files:

```
find files -type f ! -perm -u=rw
```

If you find something:

```
find -type f ! -perm -u=rw -exec chmod u+rw {} +
```

This is arguably better than using the `-R` flag with `chmod` because we don't want to give files and directories the same permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the nautilus-admin addon from the repositories you can open (right click) any file or folder and change the permissions in the Properties tab.

It's a GUI solution to the problem for those who prefer it.